# R dplyr - distinct accross all columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to specify dplyr::distinct should use all column names without resorting to nonstandard evaluation?

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2),b=c(1,1,3))

df %>% distinct(a,b,.keep_all=FALSE)          # behavior I'd like to replicate
```

vs

```
df %>% distinct(everything(),.keep_all=FALSE) # with syntax of this form
```

Comment: Does `df %>% distinct()`give you what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I believe passing the data frame as the sole argument used to yield the correct result, however recent releases have seen changes to the distinct function. I currently get: `Error: No variables selected`

Comment: `df %>% unique` works as an alternative, though not the most satisfying answer.

Comment: Is this a new bug in `dplyr`? I swear I saw it work fine. Getting same error of no variables selected.

Comment: @Gopala, not a bug. Just a design decision in the new version. I used distinct() without arguments pretty frequently , now using unique() for the same purpose.

Comment: But, unique is terribly slow. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can distinct the all columns with the code below.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data_frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  value = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d")
)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# id value
# <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     1     a
# 3     2     b
# 4     2     c
# 5     3     d
# 6     3     d

# distinct with Non-Standard Evaluation
df %>% distinct()

# distinct with Standard Evaluation
df %>% distinct_()

# Also, you can set the column names with .dots.
df %>% distinct_(.dots = names(.))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
# id value
# <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     2     b
# 3     2     c
# 4     3     d

# distinct with data.table
unique(as.data.table(df))
# id value
# 1:  1     a
# 2:  2     b
# 3:  2     c
# 4:  3     d
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.0.5 of `dplyr`, the two following options yield the same output.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 2),
                 b = c(1, 1, 3))

df %>% distinct(a, b)

  a b
1 1 1
2 2 3

df %>% distinct(across(everything()))

  a b
1 1 1
2 2 3
```

No reason to specify `.keep_all = FALSE` argument as this is the default.

You could also use `tibble()` instead of `data.frame()`