# Pass multiple column names in function to dplyr::distinct() with Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, nse

I want to specify an unknown number of column names in a function that will use `dplyr::distinct()`. My current attempt is:

```
myFunction <- function(table, id) {
  table %>%
    dplyr::distinct(.data[[id]])
}
```

I'm trying the above [`.data[[id]]`] because [the data-masking section of this dplyr blog](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) states:

> When you have an env-variable that is a character vector, you need to index into the .data pronoun with [[, like summarise(df, mean = mean(.data[[var]])).

and the documentation for `dplyr::distinct()` says about its second argument:

> `<data-masking>` Optional variables to use when determining uniqueness. If there are multiple rows for a given combination of inputs, only the first row will be preserved. If omitted, will use all variables.

#### Spark

More specifically, I'm trying to use this function with Spark.

```
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(local = "master")
mtcars_tbl <- sparklyr::copy_to(sc, mtcars, "mtcars_spark")

##### desired return
mtcars_tbl %>% dplyr::distinct(cyl, gear)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
    cyl  gear
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     4
2     4     4
3     6     3
4     8     3
5     4     3
6     4     5
7     8     5
8     6     5

##### myFunction fails
id = c("cyl", "gear")
myFunction(mtcars_tbl, id)
 Error: Can't convert a call to a string
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41866739/15723919), I have other failed attempts:

```
myFunction <- function(table, id) {
    table %>%
        dplyr::distinct(.dots = id)
}

myFunction(mtcars_tbl, id)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
  .dots           
  <list>          
1 <named list [2]>


#####


myFunction <- function(table, id) {
    table %>%
        dplyr::distinct_(id)
}

myFunction(mtcars_tbl, id)
Error in UseMethod("distinct_") : 
  no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct applies to all columns of a table at once. Consider an example table:

```
A     B
1     4
1     4
2     3
2     3
3     3
3     5
```

It is not clear what applying distinct to only column A, but not column B should return. The following example is clearly not a good choice because it breaks the relationship between columns A and B. For example, there is no (A = 2, B = 4) row in the original dataset.

```
A     B
1     4
2     4
3     3
      3
      3
      5
```

Hence the best approach is to select only those columns you want first, and then take the distinct. Something more like:

```r
myFunction <- function(table, id) {
  table %>%
    dplyr::select(dplyr::all_of(id)) %>%
    dplyr::distinct()
}
```

Comment: brilliant move to separate into two steps! Note, however, when `id = c("cyl", "gear")` (or otherwise holds more than one data-variable name), the error is `Error: Must subset the data pronoun with a string`. So I don't think you can reach my "desired return" with your current code (at least with dplyr 1.0.6). If you change your select statement to `dplyr::select(dplyr::all_of(id))`, I'll be happy to accept. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you for the correction, I did not test that part of my answer carefully. The other approach I have used is `select(!!!syms(id))`. This converts strings to symbols, but is not as clear as `all_of` for this application.